# Android sdk 21 library errors

Tags: android

I installed [Android SDK 21 bundle Windows x64](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and get nothing but errors if I try to add any code to the initial project creation code. I tried running through the Hello World and every entry gave an error. BTW: I am a newbie with Android and Linux, but I have done a lot of Windows programming. thanks...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: removed redundancy.

Comment: Post here the error you got.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message'). activity_hello_world.xml /HelloWorld/res/layout line 7 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: Does your `res/values/strings.xml` file contains string with name `edit_message`?

Comment: It does not; I added "<string name="edit_message">EditText</string>" to string.xml and the code ran. It looks like I need some basic understanding of how this works. Do you have a link to that will get me up and running? thanks again...

Comment: Try official android developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: I believe that I have come to some understanding with Eclipse tools and the Graphical editor and the code output. Somewhere there must be a list of functions and their syntax. So far I have located the [API Guides][1], but being a newbie, I am in deep water....


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Your last `Button(button_send)` didn't have any parent view.

You should to put that into a view like `LinearLayout` or others.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
1) reloading Eclipse
2) running the Project Clean.